# Windows API for invoking menu item without using simulated click

Tags: windows, api

I was wondering if there was a Windows API to invoke a menu item belonging to a window owned by a different process.

Neither simulated mouse clicks nor send keys will be sufficient because both would take over the UI for however long it takes to click through the menu items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

1. Use [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to capture the command id
2. Use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or some other function) to get window handle.
3. Use [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send the command to the window